# How can I embed a URL in an image in Salesforce surveys?

Tags: salesforce, rich-text-editor, salesforce-lightning

I'm new to Salesforce surveys and I'd like to embed a URL (for this example, https://www.google.com) in an image. I've tried following their documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_rich_text_area_limitations.htm&type=0) but it's a tad confusing. The survey's editor doesn't give any built-in options - this is what I have right now:

[image: img1]

In a wild attempt I tried:

[image: img2]

To no avail - it just displays the plain text in production. How can I embed a URL in an image (if possible)?

Comment: can you try this `<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"/></a>` ?

Comment: @Vishal No dice, just displays the line in plain text.

Comment: Can you embed javascript into the survey?

Comment: @grizzthedj I have zero clue.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a bit more I found this [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_using_html_editor.htm&type=5):

> "..Upload Image and select an image from your local host. You can upload only JPEG, PNG, or GIF files. The file cannot exceed 1 MB. **You can’t add a hyperlink to an image**. Copying inline images from external sources to the text editor is not supported."

Looks like it's not possible :(. I'm still searching for a workaround if one exists.